# Get a weighted average score for Elastic Search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bool query with different set of queries

Say like

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "match": {
          "firstName": {
            "query": "abcde",
            "fuzziness": 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "lastName": {
            "query": "qrs"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match": {
          "middleName": {
            "query": "asdfg",
            "fuzziness": 1
          }
         }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to have a threshold to match this query say 70

I have a score like 40% of the total score to lastName, 30% of the total score for firstName, 30% of the total score for middleName

So at least lastName and firstName should match or the lastName and middleName should match to satisfy the query.

How to achieve this.